# Merging of two AAC files into a single file

Tags: audio

I am trying to merge two different  AAC audio files and a H264 video file to form a single TS file using C++ code. I have been successful in it. So now my TS file possess the following order. First, video part from the video file, then audio part from the first audio file and then audio part from the second audio file and then again the video part and it goes on the same way. On hearing the resulting file, I recognized the presence of the different audio files with the video.The problem is that the resulting audio ain't that much cleared. Distortions can be recognized making it unclear to hear.  Also note that the resulting audio seems slow as compared to the original.Can anyone guide me in getting off those distortions and procuring the exact replica of my original files ?

Thanks,
Ashish.